# Is there an automatic roll forward for minor/patch versions of .NET 5 in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, .net-5

When starting a .NET 5 project locally there is an [automatic roll forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#framework-dependent-apps-roll-forward), meaning when starting the project the runtime will choose the newest minor/patch version installed on the system.

For deploy to production I use docker with a typical Dockerfile with lines like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
```

and

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
```

When typing "dotnet --info" on the server where the docker image is running on I always get version "5.0.0".

I would like to know if I have to enter the correct minor/patch versions manually in the Dockerfile each time a new version is released or if there is a version specifier to install those small versions with automatic roll forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` is a floating tag. It always [refers to the latest patch in that major.minor release](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/documentation/tagging-guidelines.md):

> The tag is updated to always reference the most recent patch that is currently available for the Major.Minor release.

For example, if you inspect the docker image today, you should see this is a 5.0.102 SDK and 5.0.2 Runtime image:

```
$ podman inspect mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 --format='json' | jq '.[0].Config.Env'
[
  "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
  "ASPNETCORE_URLS=",
  "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true",
  "DOTNET_VERSION=5.0.2",
  "ASPNET_VERSION=5.0.2",
  "DOTNET_SDK_VERSION=5.0.102",
  "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true",
  "NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip",
  "POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL=PSDocker-DotnetSDK-Debian-10"
]
```

If you are seeing that this is still `5.0.0` on you server, you might be using an older container. By default `docker run` will run the image last pulled, without checking for an update.

You might need to `docker pull` to explicitly update the image, or use `docker run --pull=always` to make sure you are running the latest container image.

Comment: Wow, you found the documentation I could not find after hours of searching! That's strange, at least I can say that every deploy successfully deploys my code changes to production. I thought it might be some caching issue that docker/jenkins sees an existing .NET 5.0.0 image and then does not fetch anything from mcr but "docker build --no-cache" option also did not help.